# ADB1000: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero. For no obvious reason

Tags: xamarin.android

So, the first time I got this error I thought I accidently edited a critical system file, so I re-installed the Android SDK and the emulator which fixed the issue.

But now I'm getting the same error. The last thing I did was implement this code

```
            mainListView.ItemClick += MainListView_ItemClick;

        private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

And the weird thing is that NONE of my xamarian.android projects run. Literally one moment it was working fine and the next for no obvious reason xamarian.android doesn't work anymore.

The error is:

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       ADB1000: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: length
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value) in E:\A_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidInstalledPackage.cs:line 55
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output) in E:\A_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 65
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 467
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0
>   "

and

> "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       ADB1000:  Deployment failed
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: length
>      at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value) in E:\A_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidInstalledPackage.cs:line 55
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output) in E:\A_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 65
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\254\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 467
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0
>   "

I appreciate your help

Comment: First of all, please update all of the nuget packages to the latest.Then delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your project folder, then rebuild your project. Can you provide a demo about this issue? Just according to your item click code, I cannot re-produce this issue.

Comment: Got exact same error, even the line numbers are same. Factory Reset of emulator worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone faced the similar issue, try the below operations.

- Deploy the app in **Release** mode.
- **Delete** it from the device manually.
- Then deploy the app in **Debug** mode.

Comment: This did not work for me. I could deploy my app in Release mode, but switching back to Debug did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Factory Reset of emulator worked for me too (As @Prashant Gupta replied in the comment above).